# How to pass as argument cells operation instead of single cell in Excel VBA UDF?

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, user-defined-functions

I've created a UDF to calculate a nonlinear equation which considers 3 arguments (A1, B1 and C1). The results comes in D1 (=SLV(A1; B1; C1)).

What I am trying to do is to give a operation between cells instead of A1, B1 or C1.
As example: instead of A1, I would like to write G1/H1^(K1*10^-4).

My UDF function is given below:

```
Function SLV(ByVal a, b, c As Range) As Single

    Dim det, root1, root2, rootf As Single

    <several operations>

    SLV = result

End Function
```

This results in error `#VALUE`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To debug, call `SLV` from a sub instead of as a UDF from the worksheet. What line throws the error? Note that you have to repeat the type in VBA, otherwise variables are actually `Variant`s: `Dim det as Single, root1 as Single, root2 as Single...`.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful tip!!! I've already change the code in variable declaration as you pointed out. My current formula is `=slv(B14/2,(Q19*S34)*10^(-4),(-Q19*S34*D14+O19*S34*L19)*10^(-4))`. However, I've come to find that only argument C gives error, not A or B. Does this help?

Comment: Well `c` shouldn't be `As Range` right?

Comment: I'm sorry for being a beginner, but I cannot pass an arguments operation as a range? Should it be declared as long?

Comment: `Function SLV(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b as Double, ByVal c As Double) As Double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You need to specify the type in variable declaration, otherwise the variables are actually `Variant`s: `Dim det as Single, root1 as Single, root2 as Single...`. Though `As Double` would be preferred here for more precision.

2: Since the arguments are no longer `Range`s, change the types:

```
Function SLV(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, ByVal c As Double) As Double

    Dim det As Double, root1 As Double, root2 As Double, rootf As Double, result As Double

    <several operations>

    SLV = result

End Function
```